# R reactable with Shiny - sort column through code

Tags: r, shiny

Using reactable R package with Shiny, how can I sort programmatically?  If the user has sorted by other columns, I want to be able to get back to the default sort order by clicking a button.  That's because the column for sorting is invisible to the user.

Here's a minimal example

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("table")
  , actionButton("sort_button", "default sort")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      iris
      , columns = list(
        Sepal.Length = colDef(show = FALSE))
      , sortable = TRUE
      , defaultSorted = list(Sepal.Length = "asc")
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

shinyApp(ui, server)

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is a table refresh. It can only happen when the data is reactive and it changes. So how to change the data without actually changing it? One option is incrementing a value by a tiny amount. Another is adding a dummy record. This trick/hack/workaround may work in some situations.

```r
library(shiny); library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
runApp( list(
ui = fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("table")
  , actionButton("sort_button", "default sort")
),
server = function(input, output) {
  r <- reactiveValues( iris2 = iris )
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      r$iris2  
      , columns = list(
        Sepal.Length = colDef(show = FALSE))
      , sortable = TRUE
      , defaultSorted = list(Sepal.Length = "asc")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$sort_button, {
    # update/restore value on each click
    if (nrow(r$iris2[with(r$iris2, which(Species=='setosa' & Sepal.Length==4.7 & Sepal.Width==3.2 & Petal.Length==1.3 & Petal.Width==0.2)),])>0)
      r$iris2 <- r$iris2 %>% mutate(Petal.Length = replace(Petal.Length, which(Species=='setosa' & Sepal.Length==4.7 & Sepal.Width==3.2 & Petal.Length==1.3 & Petal.Width==0.2), 1.301))
    else
      r$iris2 <- r$iris2 %>% mutate(Petal.Length = replace(Petal.Length, which(Species=='setosa' & Sepal.Length==4.7 & Sepal.Width==3.2 & Petal.Length==1.301 & Petal.Width==0.2), 1.3))
  })
}
))
```